# Create VUE component after page loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can I create a vue component after the page is loaded?

For example: create component X if a AJAX call is successful, or another if fails?

But i mean, create the componente in that moment, not have it hidden/disable waiting for the ajax return.

========= EDIT ==========

====== SOME CODES =======

on ajax successful, call

```
function getOptions(){
    return '<MyHappyComponent id_service="1" public="S" ></MyHappyComponent>';
}
```

Comment: Show some codes.

Comment: pretty much that, after ajax call 'print' a new component

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Dynamic & Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) with data variable to show/hide the component

```
<component v-bind:is="MyHappyComponent" id_service="1" public="S"></component>
```